tblr environment in tblr environment
When I put one tblr environment in another there is an alignment problem, it is centered when it should not as you can see in the example below.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

tblr in tblr :

\[ \begin{tblr}{cr@{\ }c@{\ }l}
            & \det( \overrightarrow{AM};\overrightarrow{AB}) &=& 0 \\
    \iff& \begin{tblr}{|cc|} x-1 & -3 \\ y+3 & 4 \\ \end{tblr}  &=& 0 \\
    \iff& 4(x-1) + 3(y+3) &=& 0 \\
\end{tblr}\]

array in tblr : 

\[ \begin{tblr}{cr@{\ }c@{\ }l}
            & \det( \overrightarrow{AM};\overrightarrow{AB}) &=& 0 \\
    \iff& \begin{array}{|cc|} x-1 & -3 \\ y+3 & 4 \\ \end{array}  &=& 0 \\
    \iff& 4(x-1) + 3(y+3) &=& 0 \\
\end{tblr}\]

\end{document}



I see no reason for using tblr in this case. And I don't think that nesting tblr is supported.

@egreg In fact, I used the tabularray +vmatrix environment but I simplified it for the example.

I don't think that you can nest tblr environments, because they seem to do global assignments.
You might prepare the inner one separately, but you have available much better tools for math alignments.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\tblrbox}

\begin{document}

Nesting \texttt{tblr} can be made to work
\[
  \sbox{\tblrbox}{$\begin{tblr}{|cc|} x-1 & -3 \\ y+3 & 4 \\ \end{tblr}$}
  \begin{tblr}{cr@{\ }c@{\ }l}
        & \det( \overrightarrow{AM};\overrightarrow{AB}) &=& 0 \\
    \iff& \usebox{\tblrbox}  &=& 0 \\
    \iff& 4(x-1) + 3(y+3) &=& 0 \\
  \end{tblr}
\]

With \texttt{array} it seems to work
\[
  \begin{tblr}{cr@{\ }c@{\ }l}
        & \det( \overrightarrow{AM};\overrightarrow{AB}) &=& 0 \\
    \iff& \begin{array}{|cc|} x-1 & -3 \\ y+3 & 4 \\ \end{array}  &=& 0 \\
    \iff& 4(x-1) + 3(y+3) &=& 0 \\
  \end{tblr}
\]

However, with \texttt{amsmath} alignments it's even better and easier
\[
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&&
  \det( \overrightarrow{AM};\overrightarrow{AB})        &= 0 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow\quad&
  \begin{vmatrix} x-1 & -3 \\ y+3 & 4 \\ \end{vmatrix}  &= 0 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow\quad&
  4(x-1) + 3(y+3)                                       &= 0
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}


